# Add extra data to WooCommerce Orders API (wp-json)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When I consume the wp-json/wc/v2/orders endpoint, I get a result similar to the following

```
[{
"id": 744276,
"parent_id": 0,
"status": "on-hold",
"currency": "BRL",
"version": "6.4.0",
"prices_include_tax": false,
"date_created": "2022-04-14T11:46:29",
"date_modified": "2022-04-14T11:46:31",
"discount_total": "0.00",
"discount_tax": "0.00",
"shipping_total": "0.00",
"shipping_tax": "0.00",
"cart_tax": "0.00",
"total": "45.59",
"total_tax": "0.00",
"customer_id": 1,
"order_key": "wc_order_iDHRxaUAWKKMS",
"billing": {
    "first_name": "Name",
    "last_name": "Last",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "BR",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "phone": ""
},
..........
```

I need to add one more field in the "**billing**" part in this result, this field would be generated only for this API. Does Woocommerce provide a filter to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'order_custom_fields');

function order_custom_fields() {
    register_rest_field(
            'shop_order',
            'custom_fields', //field name in JSON response
            array(
                'get_callback' => 'get_order_custom_fields', // custom function name 
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema' => null,
            )
    );
}

function get_order_custom_fields($object, $field_name, $request) {

    $custom_data = get_post_meta($object['id'], '_billing_email', true);
    $object['billing']['additional'] = $custom_data;
    return $object;
}
```